# Is it possible to set Jenkins pipeline node value as parameter?

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I want to set node value as a Jenkins Scripted Pipeline parameter. Something like this:

```
node('${Node}'){
    stage('Clone') {
        checkout scm
    }
}
```

The Node parameter specified as Choise Parameter.

```
node(${Node})
```

Gives an error: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method '$' found among steps

```
node("${Node}")
```

Gives an error: There are no nodes with the label ‘class hudson.model.Node’

```
node("${Node}")
```

Gives an error: There are no nodes with the label ‘${Node}’

Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the parameter to a variable in your scripted pipeline, like so ..

```
def node_to_run_on  = "${params.Node}"

node ("${node_to_run_on}") {
   ...
   ...
}
```

Or just

```
node ("${params.Node}") {
   ...
   ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me without intermediate node_to_run_on variable. Just node("${params.Node}")